# YouTube Data API V3 with iOS7 for uploading video using iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios7, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to my YouTube channel using an iPhone application that I'm implementing. Things I have done so far;

- Integrate [google-api-objectivec-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout) in to my project
- Create a project in Google API console and obtain ***Client ID*** and ***API
  key***

What I need now are,

1. To know that, can I upload a video to YouTube by giving Gmail
   address that linked with YouTube, Password, Client ID and API key without implementing Auth 2.0 seperately?
2. Sample Objective C code for uploading a video to YouTube. As an
   example, there is a [JAVA code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) that I have used in my Android
   application but there isn't Objective C code for use for my iPhone
   application.
3. What is the difference between ***gdata-objectivec-client*** and
   ***google-api-objectivec-client***?

**UPDTE**

- iOS 7 and above features, coding, tutorial is appreciated with this matter

Comment: Are you focusing on iOS5 only? iOS8 will soon be announced... well, I'm just saying...

Comment: @Raptor sorry, my mistake, I've update the question. iOS 7 and above is, what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Answer for the question 1.) is NO. Refer [35th slide of this link](http://ebookbrowsee.net/1109-google-i-o-2013-mobile-development-with-youtube-apis-best-practices-1-pdf-d497407726)

Comment: @AnujAroshA Could you please lend a hand if you figured out how to upload video to youtube!  I am having huge problems. I cant get the google-api-objectivec-client to even compile in my project. Did you import all of the files?